# writing queries on springboot

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have to write a Query on springboot due to some specific purpose but I am trying to write the queries using the values passed but It is giving tons of error and I am sure this is not the way. I have gone through Jpa and springboot documentation for @Query but didn't found anything helpful. So how to write this type of queries?

```
@Query("INSERT into LaganikartaDetails(?1)values(?2)")
void setValuesExcel(String headingValues, String fieldValues);
```

Comment: [jpa.query-methods.at-query](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)

Comment: @Patrick please look the question closely..I have already gone through that documentation. I am trying to send the fieldname and values on query through parameters.

Comment: The question is rather "why would you want to write this type of queries"? Because it looks to me that this is both the wrong way to use databases (you don't insert something field by field, but rather row by row), and the wrong way of using Hibernate (you don't handle inserts with SQL, you use something like EntityManager#persist.)

Comment: @Tobb I am writing this type of queries as in my program there is not sure which fieldname will come so I am obliged to do this. If you know any alternatives please suggest.

Comment: Maybe explain the broader sense of what problem you are trying to solve, because doing an INSERT via `@Query` seems very strange.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe I am trying to store the excel datas where sometimes excel contains 2 columns, sometimes 3 or more so i am trying to make query according to the column names that occurs

Answer (score 1):

```
Referring this, https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.5.0.RELEASE/reference/html/jpa.repositories.html

@Modifying
@Query("update User u set u.firstname = ?1 where u.lastname = ?2")
int setFixedFirstnameFor(String firstname, String lastname);

try 
@Query("INSERT into LaganikartaDetails =?1 values=?2")
void setValuesExcel(String headingValues, String fieldValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

INstaed of using insert method , You can use repository save method . It will automatically save whatever the object that you trying to save by using repository methods. Here I will share one code snippet for simulating insertion into database,

```
@Autowired
DriverRepository driverRepo;

@RequestMapping(value="/driverSubmit", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView driverSubmit(@ModelAttribute Driver driver) 
    {
        driverRepo.save(driver);
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/driverHome");  
    }
```

Here driverRepo is repository object that is autowired here. You mention which is the object data with calling of .save method. This is the spring data JPA repository method. You don't need to use insert query.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert manually with this query:

```
@Query("INSERT into LaganikartaDetails =? values=?")
void setValuesExcel(String headingValues, String fieldValues);
```

Answer (score 0):

If the fields that need to be persisted in entity are dynamic, then a mapper class can be created to check if input attribute is not null or empty then set it in entity. In the end you can call entity.save().

for example:

Employee has attributes name,salary,age,contact number
you can write something like below
`if(StringUtils.isNotBlank(name){ employee.setName(name); }`

similarly for other fields, once this is done for all fields in the end you can call employee.save()